# body-parser deprecated undefined extended

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded())
const port = 3000
//Endpoint to serve the HTML
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile("pages/index.html", {root: __dirname})
})

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("pages/login.html", {root: __dirname})
 })

app.get('/signup', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("pages/signup.html", {root: __dirname})
})
//Endpoint for APIs
app.post('/getnotes', (req, res) => {
const {userToken } = req.body
  res.sendFile("pages/signup.html", {root: __dirname})
})

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const {userToken } = req.body
  res.sendFile("pages/signup.html", {root: __dirname})
})

app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
  const {userToken } = req.body
  res.sendFile("pages/signup.html", {root: __dirname})
})

app.post('/addnote', (req, res) => {
  const {userToken } = req.body
  res.sendFile("pages/signup.html", {root: __dirname})
})

app.post('/deletenote', (req, res) => {
  const {userToken } = req.body
  res.sendFile("pages/signup.html", {root: __dirname})
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

when im try to connect my webpage to backend node.js its shows me below line:
when its execute its shows a error

body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option index.js:4:17

Answer (score 0):

Because [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/commit/b7420f8dc5c8b17a277c9e50d72bbaf3086a3900) has been deprecated.

You can re-write constructure as below to prevent warning, by passing ***extended*** option.

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))
```